# [iPhone]How to deploy a app with Application Preferences to real device

Tags: iphone, preferences, jailbreak

Every thing is OK in simulator but when I deploy my app to real device (jailbroken) I can't find app's Application Preferences in Setting or my iPhone!

What wrong?! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean the settings bundle within the project. If it works in the simulator and not in the device there is a good chance that the problem is case sensitivity. Check that the name of the settings bundle is `Settings.bundle`

Comment: I don't think that is my problem. My settings bundle named Settings.budle.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake, Settings.bundle.